# Finding common list sequences

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of lists. Each list is a sequence of numbers. No two lists are equal but two or more lists may start with the same sequence of numbers (see my example input below). What I want to do is find these common sequences and make them a new element in the dictionary.

Sample input:

```
sequences = {
    18: [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 12, 15, 17, 18],
    19: [1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 13, 14, 16, 19],
    25: [1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 13, 14, 20, 25],
    11: [0, 2, 4, 7, 11],
    20: [0, 2, 4, 10, 20],
    26: [21, 23, 26],
}
```

Sample output:

```
expected_output = {
    6: [1, 3, 5, 6],
    18: [8, 12, 15, 17, 18],
    14: [9, 13, 14],
    19: [16, 19],
    25: [20, 25],
    4: [0, 2, 4],
    11: [7, 11],
    20: [10, 20],
    26: [21, 23, 26],
}
```

The key of each list is its last element. Order doesn't matter.

I have a working code. However, it's very messy. Could somebody suggest a simpler/cleaner solution?

```
from collections import Counter

def split_lists(sequences):
    # get first elem from each sequence
    firsts = list(map(lambda s: s[0], sequences))

    # get non-duplicate first elements
    not_duplicates = list(map(lambda c: c[0], filter(lambda c: c[1] == 1, Counter(firsts).items())))

    # start the new_sequences with the non-duplicate lists
    new_sequences = dict(map(lambda s: (s[-1], s), filter(lambda s: s[0] in not_duplicates, sequences)))

    # get duplicate first elements
    duplicates = list(map(lambda c: c[0], filter(lambda c: c[1] > 1, Counter(firsts).items())))
    for duplicate in duplicates:
        # get all lists that start with the duplicate element
        duplicate_lists = list(filter(lambda s: s[0] == duplicate, sequences))

        # get the common elements from the duplicate lists and make it a new
        # list to add to our new_sequences dict
        repeated_sequence = sorted(list(set.intersection(*list(map(set, duplicate_lists)))))
        new_sequences[repeated_sequence[-1]] = repeated_sequence

        # get lists from where I left of
        i = len(repeated_sequence)
        sub_lists = list(filter(lambda s: len(s) > 0, map(lambda s: s[i:], duplicate_lists)))

        # recursively split them and store them in new_sequences
        new_sequences.update(split_lists(sub_lists))

    return new_sequences
```

Also, could you help me figure out the complexity of my algo? Recursion makes me dizzy. My best guess is `O(n*m)` where `n` is the number of lists and `m` the length of the longest list.

Comment: how long does the common sub-sequence have to be, to be considered a *sequence*?

Comment: are the lists sorted?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis any length from 1 to len(seq) - 1

Comment: @ReutSharabani yes they are

Comment: This is the longest common substring problem.

Comment: How did this element came to be: `18: [8, 12, 15, 17, 18],`?

Comment: The first longest common sequence between the first three lists is `[1, 3, 5, 6]` so I remove that from list `18` and end up with two elements: `6: [1, 3, 5, 6]` and `18: [8, 12, 15, 17, 18]`, then `18` doesn't have any more common sequences with any other list so it stays like that

Comment: @damores I think a functional approach is clearer (standard library names which are commonly used) and more concise. When you're working with collections there are very good functions ready to be imported in the standard library (especially in `itertools` and `collections`). Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seperate this into logical functions:

- Find out which sequences start with the same element
- Find the common elements

## same start:

Can be done easily with a `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
def same_start(sequences):
    same_start = defaultdict(list)
    for seq in sequences:
        same_start[seq[0]].append(seq)
    return same_start.values()
```

> ```
> list(same_start(sequences.values()))
> ```

```
[[[1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 12, 15, 17, 18],
  [1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 13, 14, 16, 19],
  [1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 13, 14, 20, 25]],
 [[0, 2, 4, 7, 11], [0, 2, 4, 10, 20]],
 [[21, 23, 26]]]
```

## Find the common elements:

a simple generator that yields values as long as they are all the same

```
def get_beginning(sequences):
    for values in zip(*sequences):
        v0 = values[0]
        if not all(i == v0 for i in values):
            return
        yield v0
```

## aggregating

```
def aggregate(same_start):
    for seq in same_start:
        if len(seq) < 2:
            yield  seq[0]
            continue
        start = list(get_beginning(seq))
        yield start
        yield from (i[len(start):] for i in seq)
```

> ```
> list(aggregate(same_start(sequences.values())))
> ```

```
[[1, 3, 5, 6],
 [8, 12, 15, 17, 18],
 [9, 13, 14, 16, 19],
 [9, 13, 14, 20, 25],
 [0, 2, 4],
 [7, 11],
 [10, 20],
 [21, 23, 26]]
```

## Further on

If you want to combine sequences `18` and `25`, then you can do something like this

```
def combine(sequences):
    while True:
        s = same_start(sequences)
        if all(len(i) == 1 for i in s):
            return sequences
        sequences = tuple(aggregate(s))
```

> ```
> {i[-1]: i for i in combine(sequences.values())}
> ```

```
{4: [0, 2, 4],
 6: [1, 3, 5, 6],
 11: [7, 11],
 14: [9, 13, 14],
 18: [8, 12, 15, 17, 18],
 19: [16, 19],
 20: [10, 20],
 25: [20, 25],
 26: [21, 23, 26]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I like the use of generators and the overall readability. This code is much cleaner than mine

Answer (score 2):

Using some functional tools this is what I came up with (assuming sequences are sorted). The gist is in `find_longest_prefixes`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from itertools import chain, takewhile
from collections import defaultdict

sequences = {
    18: [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 12, 15, 17, 18],
    19: [1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 13, 14, 16, 19],
    25: [1, 3, 5, 6, 9, 13, 14, 20, 25],
    11: [0, 2, 4, 7, 11],
    20: [0, 2, 4, 10, 20],
    26: [21, 23, 26],
}

def flatmap(f, it):
    return chain.from_iterable(map(f, it))

def all_items_equal(items):
    return len(set(items)) == 1

def group_by_first_item(ls):
    groups = defaultdict(list)
    for l in ls:
        groups[l[0]].append(l)
    return groups.values()

def find_longest_prefixes(ls):
    # takewhile gives us common prefix easily
    longest_prefix = list(takewhile(all_items_equal, zip(*ls)))
    if longest_prefix:
       yield tuple(vs[0] for vs in longest_prefix)
    # yield suffix per iterable
    leftovers = filter(None, tuple(l[len(longest_prefix):] for l in ls))
    leftover_groups = group_by_first_item(leftovers)
    yield from flatmap(find_longest_prefixes, leftover_groups)

# apply the prefix finder to all groups
all_sequences = find_longest_prefixes(sequences.values())

# create the result structure expected
results = {v[-1]: v for v in all_sequences}

print(results)
```

The value for result is then:

```
{4: (0, 2, 4),
 6: (1, 3, 5, 6),
 11: (7, 11),
 18: (8, 12, 15, 17, 18),
 19: (9, 13, 14, 16, 19),
 20: (10, 20),
 25: (9, 13, 14, 20, 25),
 26: (21, 23, 26)}
```

Note that these are tuples which I prefer for their immutability.

Comment: very nice answer. You will need a second pass to further combine sequences 19 and 25

Comment: Recursion can be nicer than a second pass. I'll add it when I get the chance

Comment: @MaartenFabré fixed, added it recursively.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I like the use of generators and itertools. The code is much more readable than mine. I think overall @MaartenFabré's code is a bit more readable so I'm gonna go with his answer